# Can the elections page show how many questions a user has voted to close/delete/protect?

Tags: feature-request, election

This seems like a good statistic to have: it shows how much someone does several important moderation duties.

Also, the elections page shows how many flags that user made, but that's not the whole story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *would* be good information to have.

However, it's not currently public information (you can see close voter names after a question has been closed, but the actual votes are private). Also, so far as I can tell we've only *tracked* this information for a bit less than a year (prior to that, close votes were hard deleted) so the most useful statistic (success rate for close/re-open) could only be accurate for the past 10 months.

I don't think we can in good conscience reveal raw vote numbers, but if individual nominees want to post this, they're free to do so.

Comment: Do we have access to that for protected question count even?

Comment: I don't believe so. And frankly, I wouldn't find that particularly interesting anyway. Close and Reopen votes can be found on your profile's Votes tab (along with delete/undelete).

Comment: Given that a successful close/reopen requires a decent view velocity is that metric *really* important? Even if it is, I would expect 10 months to be enough to do relative comparison. Also isn't flag-count non-public? Shouldn't you be hiding that as well?

Comment: Looking at it I think we can't give any real numbers even if we wanted since the votes tab doesn't give totals and only seems to show activity on non-deleted questions where the vote hasn't expired. (Not sure if I would quote that verbatim or not given the choice and character limit and it's too late this time anyway)

Comment: Wait, could you post the number of close votes that resulted in a closed question, since that information is public (you see who voted for the question to be closed once the question is closed)? Or, did you not track that either? That could still be good information to have, even if it's incomplete.

Comment: @Christofian: that seems reasonable.

Comment: @Shog9 could you talk to the dev team about implementing this? Flags only tell part of the story, since many people close things instead of flagging them.

Comment: @Christofian: probably too late this time around, but I'll definitely be suggesting it for a future election.

Comment: This topic just came up again in the SO November 2015 elections (see @bjb568's comment to my nomination). The original reasoning of lack of collected data seems less relevant now, more than three years later. Can we ask to reevaluate this request?