# Why can I see other users close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, review

I always thought that close-vote decisions should be private *until they may result in an actual action* and are in fact private. But I can see the review progress of other users:

[image: other user review decision]

Is this wanted behaviour?

Comment: Sort-of private... it always shows who all voted to close a thread. I have no idea what the desired behavior is.

Comment: I'd guess that the info is clutter on a question, not hidden because it's "private until".  However, I would say that sone people would feel uncomfortable VTCing without others backing them up and thus it's a "feature".

Comment: The normal close vote is private - I think the review decision for closing should also be private?

Comment: It's private until the question is actually closed, no?

Comment: No it's not private until the question is actually closed. I can see the review decisions (close/don't close) instantly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this may be splitting hairs, but... You're *not* actually seeing close votes.

If you wanna see your close votes, [look here](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/440/flow?tab=votes&sort=closure) (Note: people who are not Flow, don't bother following that link - you can't see Flow's close votes because they're *private*).

What you *are* seeing are your review actions. Which... Happen to equate to close votes in some cases. Unlike voting, review actions are **public** (with some exceptions to be noted later on). Following the model of suggested edits, we're doing our best to make the effort you put into this sort of site up-keep visible - both to show it off (I would hope it is a source of pride for you) and as a means of keeping moderation a *community* process - like asking, answering, and editing, your /review actions are subject to the scrutiny of your peers.

There will be, by necessity, exceptions to this. Currently, that means *delete* votes (and recommendations) don't show up, since they tended to disappear when successful. I expect when we get the New User Posts queue set up there'll be stuff hidden there as well, simply because of the nature of the actions taken there (but, this is still being hashed out - feel free to post suggestions if you like).

Of course, the elephant in the room is that, like it or not, this *can* expose some information that may not have been visible in the past. So let me emphasize:

- Only close votes cast from the context of the /review queue are exposed in this fashion.
- You cannot feasibly determine who has voted to close a not-yet-closed post, unless you already know or suspect who has voted to close a specific not-yet-closed post... *And* the close-voters all voted from the /review queue.

In practice, this should all but eliminate the danger of unwanted harassment, while improving transparency and opening the door to [certain features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135565/can-the-elections-page-show-how-many-questions-a-user-has-voted-to-close-delete) I wish could have been implemented sooner.

Naturally, if you *do* encounter harassment (feedback is one thing, but badgering is quite another), please let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This Q came from meta.android.SE with a small [user count](http://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) with VC privileges. There's definitely no harassment (yet). So I guess it's just been asked for curiosity by @Flow. :-)

Comment: so.. from a philosophical perspective, is the intent that pending close votes "should be" private, but the mechanics of review leaks them, or that close votes are "public information", but the current close-this-question mechanic just doesn't show them (e.g. to minimize harrassment)?

Comment: From a philosophical perspective, close votes have never really been *completely private*, @KutuluMike - I'll spare you the history (you probably already know it) but if nothing else once a question is closed they're public record. The problem is, the system has never exposed them consistently, so there's a reasonable *expectation* that they're not going to be visible in many situations, one that's slowly eroded over the years but still present to a large degree - so violating that without good cause is likely to generate complaints.

Comment: thanks. as you may have guessed, it _has_ generated a complaint, and I was surprised that anyone considered them private in the first place :)

Comment: I think I know what you're referring to, @KutuluMike - so I posted an answer. More than one layer of naivete there.