# Helpful flags count in election nomination

Tags: support, election, nominations, helpful-flags

We are showing the helpful flags count of the nominees in the election nomination page.

It shows that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2876565/the-wobbuffet) nominee has less than 80 helpful flags. Users without Deputy badge can't nominate for election. So, I came to a conclusion that it might represent the helpful flag count for meta site not for Stack Overflow.

Before seeing this, I thought that the count is for SO.

First of all, it is unclear that the helpful flags count is for which site.

[This candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp) has earned Marshal badge in Stack Overflow, but showing less than 500 helpful flags and he doesn't have Deputy badge in meta.

Then, I think that showing the helpful flags count for meta site is not as much important than showing the count for main site.

Flagging in main site is differ from flagging in meta.

I request the community to show helpful flags count for main site or for both main and meta(if possible with declined, disputed count will be more beneficial to judge).

Comment: +1 i was just hitting the submit button on that ..and saw your question

Comment: If that's flags on Meta, then bluefeet's 20k+ helpful flags becomes totally insane (rather than just enormously awesome).

Comment: @Mat, blufeet doesn't have marshal badge for meta, Oh it's a bug.

Comment: From the stats on my nomination, I can confirm the helpful flag count is for main, not meta. I *think* the required badges are more of a recommended list of badges, and are not actually *required* to apply... again, I *think*.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian There is more SO specific info [on this page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow).

Comment: But it seems weird that my helpful flags count in my profile doesn't match up to what's on the nomination page. For example, it shows 1890 helpful flags in my profile, but on the nomination page it shows 1691 helpful flags.

Comment: I am quite confused about what you are asking here. The flag count shown is for SO, and there is no point in showing flag count for meta.

Comment: @Matt - I guessed the same. But only question I have is how could he earn [Deputy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy?userid=2876565) badge if he has not raised more than 80 helpful flags? My another guess for this is: comments flags do not count in nomination.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Can you tell me how many comment flags have you raised successfully? (count of helpful comments)

Comment: @hims056, or it counts only moderator attention flags, since election is for moderator position ;).

Comment: @hims056: I've raised 571 comment flags in total -- 553 were helpful and 14 were declined -- that doesn't match up.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Now only devs can answer this.

Comment: @hims056: I can't answer that :). For me, comment flags *do* count in my nomination, and the value shown in my nomination is exactly the same as what's shown on my "helpful flags" value on my profile page, which is *exactly* the same as the sum as *all* of my helpful flags (moderator attention, spam, offensive and comments) http://i.stack.imgur.com/SJH1t.png.

Comment: @Matt: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPOA.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/fz2Ow.png

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Now  that is baffling :).

Comment: The election is on SO, not mSO

Comment: As a further data point, my nomination and profile show the exact same number of helpful flags, and both numbers include comment flags.

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with the meta site.

Close flags are excluded from the count shown on the election page, as they *aren't actually reviewed by moderators anymore* - unlike the other flag types, they always go straight to the Close Review queue and skip the mod queue entirely.

Including details on the accuracy of close flags would be interesting, but kinda unfair to the candidates who can (and have) actually *voted* to close. See: [Can the elections page show how many questions a user has voted to close/delete/protect?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135565/can-the-elections-page-show-how-many-questions-a-user-has-voted-to-close-delete) for perhaps a better suggestion.